# Role of spring-aspects jar in AOP?

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have following dependencies using in my pom

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${version.aspectj}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${version.aspectj}</version>
        </dependency>
```

I ready couple of tutorial on net but no one says to include `spring-aspects` dependency. I am not sure what role does it way in applying aspects.
Can someone explain why we need `spring-aspects` ?

Also as per mine understanding spring load time weaving is based on proxy . Javagent does not play any role here. Right ?

Comment: It's all in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj).

Answer (score 0):

It increases Spring AOP functionalities I'd say one of the most common use is to add @Configurable tag that usually is used (but not necessarily )to allow DAO to access the Data Access Layer.

This JAR is a small library of AspectJ that is included in Spring.